# Can't resolve the issue : unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'dict' and 'set'

Tags: python

I am writing a dfs tree traversal code:

```
graph = {
    1 : {2,3},
    2 : {4,5},
    3 : {}    
}

def dfs(graph,start):
  visited = set()
  stack = [start]
  while stack:
    vertex = stack.pop()
    if vertex not in visited:
      visited.add(vertex)
    stack = list(graph[vertex] - visited) + stack
  return visited

v = dfs(graph,1)
```

When calling the function v = dfs(graph,1) the following error occurs:

```
<ipython-input-25-81ccabb8c90b> in dfs(graph, start)
      6     if vertex not in visited:
      7       visited.add(vertex)
----> 8     stack = list(graph[vertex] - visited) + stack
      9   return visited

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'dict' and 'set'
```

Isn't the graph returning a set when calling graph[vertex] from the dictionary? Then why operation giving TypeError?

Answer (score 2):

`{}` is an empty dictionary, not an empty set. So when `vertex == 3`, `graph[vertex]` is a dictionary, not a set, and `graph[vertex] - visited` fails.

To make an empty set, use `set()`.

```
graph = {
    1 : {2,3},
    2 : {4,5},
    3 : set()    
}
```

Comment: Yah got it. But I am getting the dfs traversal wrong.

Comment: @develop_code well that's another problem and can be a new question... If the current one is solved, you can mark the answer as accepted

Comment: @develop_code Try adding `print(stack)` and `print(visited)` to the `while` loop to see how it's progressing.

Comment: `graph[2]` has `{4, 5}`, but there's no `graph[4]` or `graph[5]`. Where are those edges supposed to go to?

Comment: Actually the graph is like this: graph = {
    1 : {2,3},
    2 : {4,5},
    3 : set(),
    4 : set(),
    5 : set()    
}

Comment: You're returning a `set` rather than a `list`. So there's no way to tell from the result whether it visited in DFS or BFS order.

Comment: Yes. Earlier when visited = set() I was getting visited = {1,2,3,4,5} . Changing visited = [] I got visited = [1,3,2,5,4] and reversing it I am getting the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are confusing `{}` which is an empty dict with `set()` that is the empty set.

```py
graph = {
    1 : {2,3},
    2 : {4,5},
    3 : set() # change this line   
}

def dfs(graph,start):
  visited = set()
  stack = [start]
  while stack:
    vertex = stack.pop()
    if vertex not in visited:
      visited.add(vertex)
    stack = list(graph[vertex] - visited) + stack
  return visited

v = dfs(graph,1)
```

If you do not want to use `set()` you can alternatively use `{*()}`.