# Need to repeat the same loop within each loop an unknown number of times in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, recursion

I am new to programming and really don't know how to express my problem, so here is the code:

```
mapping_dict = {
    0: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    1: [7, 8, 9],
    2: [10, 11, 12],
    3: [],
    4: [],
    5: [],
    6: [],
    7: [13, 14],
    8: [],
    9: [],
    10: [],
    11: [], 
    12: [],
    13: [],
    14: []
}
proper_id_list = []
```

The keys and values in the `mapping_dict` may be strings too. I need something like this:

```
proper_id_list = [0,1,7,13,14,8,9,2,10,11,12,3,4,5,6]
```

Whats going on here is that each list must be appended right after their keys.

So far, the code I could come up with, is as follows:

```
for a in mapping_dict[0]:
    proper_id_list.append(a)
    for a in mapping_dict[0]:
        proper_id_list.append(a)
        for a in mapping_dict[0]:
            proper_id_list.append(a)  # ... this will keep repeating, God knows how many times
```

I have hard coded these loops a 20 times and they work but I know this is poor design, restricted to 20 levels and the top level key in the `mapping_dict` must be a 0.

I hope this makes sense. Please help!

Comment: This is a depth-first search. Google it for algorithms.

Comment: You're traversing a tree structure.  As @Barmar says, look up how to do a depth-first tree traversal.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63398935/cant-resolve-the-issue-unsupported-operand-types-for-dict-and-set/63399055#63399055) for example

Answer (score 1):

You actually only need a single loop. Start with the lowest key, sort the keys, find them in the list, and insert their respective values.

```
proper_id = [min(mapping_dict)]
for k in sorted(mapping_dict):
    i = proper_id.index(k)
    proper_id[i+1:i+1] = mapping_dict[k]

print(proper_id)
# -> [0, 1, 7, 13, 14, 8, 9, 2, 10, 11, 12, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

However, based on the comments about depth-first search, I might be missing the point. This might not generalize, or might be very slow for large datasets since it's O(n**2).

Comment: The data set will never be too big. 5000 items in extreme cases. However, the keys cannot be sorted. These are actually IDs of rows in the database and their order can change. 1 is not necessarily higher up the tree than 2 or the other way round.